# I can't change icon of item menu Toolbar when add/ Remove Movie in Favorite List

Tags: android, toolbar

I would like to change icon of item action_favorite in Menu Toolbar. When I click item toobar_fav It wil change icon White Heart, I click item toolbar_fav one more time it will change icon Red Heart.
Beside, When I click FloatingActionButton also will change icon of item action_favorite. Now I have no any ideas for this. I tried but It's not working
This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.movie_detail);
    movieViewModel = new ViewModelProviders().of(this).get(MovieViewModel.class);
    movieDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), MovieDatabase.class, "table_demo").build();
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_movie_detail);
    favItem = findViewById(R.id.toobar_fav);
    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab_favorite);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
private void initToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);
    mMenu = menu;
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if (mMenu != null && (!isExpanded || mMenu.size() != 2)) {
        //collapse
        mMenu.add("Favorite").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_white).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    //            
    } else {
        //expaned
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(mMenu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    movie = new Detail(idMovie, favPoster, favRelease, favTitle, favVote, category, "", "");
    if(item.getTitle() == "Favorite"){
        if (movieViewModel.isFavorite(idMovie)) {
            floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_love_white);
            movieViewModel.RemoveFavList(movie);
            Toast.makeText(MovieDetail.this, "Movie is deleted from Favorite List", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MovieDetail.this, AdapterFavorite.class);
            floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red);
            movieViewModel.addFavList(movie);
            Toast.makeText(MovieDetail.this, "Movie is added to Favorite List", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

 public void initFavorite() {
    movie = new Detail(idMovie, favPoster, favRelease, favTitle, favVote, category, "", "");
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (movieViewModel.isFavorite(idMovie)) {
                floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_love_white);
                movieViewModel.RemoveFavList(movie);
                Toast.makeText(MovieDetail.this, "Movie is deleted from  Favorite List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red);
                movieViewModel.addFavList(movie);
                Toast.makeText(MovieDetail.this, "Movie is added to Favorite List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can't compare `String`s with `==` in Java, these are different objects. this will work in Kotlin only

exchange this line

```
if(item.getTitle() == "Favorite"){
```

to this

```
if("Favorite".equals(item.getTitle())){
```